# maven-jar-plugin mainClass - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, grpc, executable-jar, grpc-java

I've specified a plugin in my maven to build the jar using maven-jar-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.example.Authentication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Error

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Authentication Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/BindableService

Context:

I'm running the jar file via IntelliJ -> Jar Application Run configuration, no VM options or passing any Program arguments.

```
public class Authentication extends AuthenticationGrpc.AuthenticationImplBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
                .addService(new Authentication())
                .build();

        server.start();
        server.awaitTermination();
        System.out.println("Server listening at 8080");
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**

P.S. I unzipped .jar file and can confirm that I can see Authentication.class file there, perhaps it has to do something with grpc not able to find the class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)** you use is a very basic plugin that enables to generate a JAR, but it does not add the maven dependencies inside the final JAR.

To create an executable fat JAR, consider using one of the following plugins:

**[maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)**

This plugin adds all dependencies inside the final JAR.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.example.Authentication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

[**maven-shade-plugin**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

This plugin adds all dependencies inside the final JAR and executes shading (i.e. renaming)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.example.Authentication</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to run the jar from command prompt ?

Comment: executed `java -jar Server/target/Server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ` same output in the console

Comment: just want to bring this to attention, it's another library within jar that's causing the error, I think the caller library is not embedded, can you please help me out there. See `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/BindableService`, I don't see this io.grpc in my jar file anywhere... maybe that's the actual problem, embedding a dependency inside jar file

Comment: You might not be creating a fat jar which contains all the dependent jars.Please use'Maven Assembly Plugin' to create a fat jar.

Please follow this link : https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/