# Why does Maven run maven-jar-plugin when I specified maven-assembly-plugin in the pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a `pom.xml` which *was* using the `maven-jar-plugin` for the `package` step. I have tried to change this to `maven-assembly-plugin` for the same lifecycle step, however the output from `mvn package` suggests to me that the changes haven't been picked up.

Here's the output of `mvn package` after `mvn clean`. (Last few lines.)

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/debian/Java/Sort-List/sort-list/target/sort-list-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.780 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-08T16:24:35+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see above, it prints `maven-jar-plugin:2.4`. Why is this being printed instead of something from `maven-assembly-plugin`? This suggests to me the "wrong" plugin is being run. But I don't understand why.

Here's my full `pom.xml`. I commented out the existing `maven-jar-plugin` and replace it with `maven-assembly-plugin`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.sortlist</groupId>
  <artifactId>sort-list</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>sort-list</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <!--
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.sortlist.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        -->

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.sortlist.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

With the previous version of this POM, I was able to build a `.jar`, and execute it successfully.

Some information has been taken from an answer under this question: [maven-jar-plugin mainClass - Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447228/maven-jar-plugin-mainclass-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: 1. [Plugin bindings for jar packaging](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) 2. [When no packaging is declared, Maven assumes the packaging is the default: jar](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#packaging)

Comment: What was the reason to use the maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise What's the reason not to use it?

Comment: That does not answer the question nor does it help to understand the reasons why you have integrated that in your setup?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have no idea what you're trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Maven plugin (even your own) can bind one or more goals to a lifecycle phase.

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>baz-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>an-execution-id</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase> <!-- lifecycle phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>bazinga</goal> <!-- goal that bound to lifecycle phase -->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now a Maven build (e.g. package) `mvn package` will run `foo.bar:baz-maven-plugin:1.0.0:bazinga` goal when the build enters the `process-resources` phase.

Also Maven has a core concept called **Convention over Configuration**. Based on this concept nothing special need to be configured which have a default value.

This simple `pom.xml` will compile, run tests, create package and it also able to install packaged artifact to local repository if you run `mvn package`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.sortlist</groupId>
    <artifactId>sort-list</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

```
spinner@bistromath:/work/source/so-75966110$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.mycompany.sortlist:sort-list >------------------
[INFO] Building sort-list 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /work/source/so-75966110/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /work/source/so-75966110/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Building jar: /work/source/so-75966110/target/sort-list-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ sort-list ---
[INFO] Installing /work/source/so-75966110/target/sort-list-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /work/data/maven/com/mycompany/sortlist/sort-list/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sort-list-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /work/source/so-75966110/pom.xml to /work/data/maven/com/mycompany/sortlist/sort-list/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sort-list-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.430 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-08T18:35:40+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see a couple of plugin have activated in different phases of build lifecycle, but nothing was configured in the project's `pom.xml`.

That's because most common Maven plugins have been configured already in Super POM.

With that simple `pom.xml` just run

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

This goal

> Displays the effective POM as an XML for this build, with the active profiles factored in, or a specified artifact. If verbose, a comment is added to each XML element describing the origin of the line.

The relevant part of the verbose output is:

```xml
<build>
    <!--  ....  -->
    <plugins>
        <!--  ....  -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
            <version>2.4</version>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
                    <phase>package</phase>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you can see that `maven-jar-plugin` bound to `package` phase automatically. So if you just remove that plugin configuration from project's `pom.xml` that will use inherited configuration from Super POM.

However **I do not recommend to disable** jar plugin you can do it by override basic configuration and assign that execution to a phase which never run. That phase called `none`.

**To disable jar plugin use this configuation**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.sortlist</groupId>
    <artifactId>sort-list</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE to activate `maven-assembly-plugin`.**

There are two section in `pom.xml` to configure plugins.

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!--            -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!--            -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

> **pluginManagement**: is an element that is seen along side plugins. Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way, except that rather than configuring plugin information for this particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children or in the current POM. The children have every right to override pluginManagement definitions.

So, in `<pluginManagement>` section you can configure common settings (e.g. in a multi module project) of a certain plugin.

In the `<build><plugins>` section you can set the certain invocation of the plugin.

`<pluginManagement>` is optional, but every configured settings can override in `<plugins>` section.

To execute a plugin's goal it must be defined in `<plugins>` section.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.sortlist</groupId>
    <artifactId>sort-list</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- specify version and default lifecycle binding WITHOUT execution -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- add project specific configuration AND execute previously configured goal -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.sortlist.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Of course, if you don't want or don't need to manage this plugin the configuration can be merged under `<plugins>` and then, the entry under `<pluginManagement>` is no longer required.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where is this super pom located, for interest? And why doesn't my pom run the assembly plugin?

Comment: Super POM located under maven home `[MAVEN_HOME]/lib/maven-model-builder-[maven-version].jar:org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml`
I'll update my answer to enable assembly plugin.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant answer has just updated with details of assemly plugin invocation .

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. For me this raises a final question. What is the point of `pluginManagement` in the case where I only have a single `pom.xml`? I don't have any child pom's, so doesn't it become redundant?

Comment: In that case all definition could be placed under `<plugins>`. `<pluginManagement>` gives optional capability for some "abstraction". Honestly I also would put all assemly plugin configuration under `<plugins>` section. I just tried to illustrate how those sections work together.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up a major point of confusion for me. If a plugin has an `execution` and/or `configuration` XML tag, should the `execution`/`configuration` stuff go in the "plugins" section or the "pluginManagement->plugins" section ?