# Why is Maven downloading log4j-1.2.17.jar?

Tags: maven, log4j, mule-maven-plugin

I have a Mule app that I am building with Maven. I am trying to make sure it does not download log4j-1.2.17.jar when building. However,
the jar appears in

```
repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

This version of log4j is not a dependency of any of my dependencies. This is the the output of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-apikit-module:jar:mule-plugin:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.2.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.apikit:parser-service:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.apikit:raml-parser-interface:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.apikit:raml-parser-interface-impl-v1:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.raml:raml-parser:jar:0.8.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  |     \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.apikit:raml-parser-interface-impl-v2:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.raml:raml-parser-2:jar:1.0.40:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.raml:yagi:jar:1.0.40:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mule.apikit:raml-parser-interface-impl-amf:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.github.amlorg:amf-client_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- com.github.amlorg:amf-webapi_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- com.damnhandy:handy-uri-templates:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- com.github.amlorg:amf-validation_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- com.github.scopt:scopt_2.12:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.json4s:json4s-native_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.topbraid:shacl:jar:1.2.0-INTERNAL:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.jena:jena-arq:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.apache.jena:jena-core:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     |  +- org.apache.jena:jena-iri:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     |  \- org.apache.jena:jena-base:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     |     \- com.github.andrewoma.dexx:collection:jar:0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.apache.jena:jena-shaded-guava:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java:jar:0.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- com.github.amlorg:amf-aml_2.12:jar:4.0.118:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- com.github.amlorg:amf-core_2.12:jar:4.0.102:compile
[INFO] |  |     |        \- org.mule.syaml:syaml_2.12:jar:0.7.254:compile
[INFO] |  |     |           \- org.mule.common:scala-common_2.12:jar:0.5.60:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.mule.amf:amf-xml-extension_2.12:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.rackspace.apache:xerces2-xsd11:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  +- com.rackspace.eclipse.webtools.sourceediting:org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor:jar:2.1.100:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  |  \- edu.princeton.cup:java-cup:jar:10k:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:64.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.connectors:mule-objectstore-connector:jar:mule-plugin:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.connectors:mule-amazon-s3-connector:jar:mule-plugin:5.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.604:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.604:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.604:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.604:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.604:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.connectors:aws-connector-commons:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.11.604:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mulesoft.connectors:mule-connector-commons:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.mule.connectors:atlantic-commons:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-file-extension-common:jar:mule-plugin:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.connectors:mule-file-connector:jar:mule-plugin:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] +- 7dd46d49-119f-4b70-a1b4-7d0acc3fbc25:mule-a2z-aws-secrets-manager:jar:mule-plugin:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:jar:1.11.339:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-caching-java:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.connectors:mule-http-connector:jar:mule-plugin:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-cors-kernel:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.connectors:mule-sockets-connector:jar:mule-plugin:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-validation-module:jar:mule-plugin:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- 7dd46d49-119f-4b70-a1b4-7d0acc3fbc25:common-error-handler:jar:mule-plugin:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.munit:munit-tools:jar:mule-plugin:2.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.munit:munit-assert:jar:2.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.munit:munit-mock:jar:2.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.weave:assertions:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mule.weave:wlang:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.connectors:mule-salesforce-connector:jar:mule-plugin:9.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.force.api:force-wsc:jar:48.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.force.api:force-metadata-api:jar:48.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.force.api:force-partner-api:jar:48.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.cometd.java:bayeux-api:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-common:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.2.26.v20180806:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.intellij:annotations:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-storage-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-impl:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-messaging-api:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr4:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.4.0-b03:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi:jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.xml.soap:jakarta.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-basic:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-tf:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-asm:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-dynamic:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-basic-tools:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-tf-tools:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:1.5.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20170516:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.65:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.module:mule-java-module:jar:mule-plugin:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.connectors:mule-amazon-sqs-connector:jar:mule-plugin:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.mule.modules:mule-custom-metrics-extension:jar:mule-plugin:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.munit:munit-runner:jar:mule-plugin:2.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.munit:munit-common:jar:2.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] \- 7dd46d49-119f-4b70-a1b4-7d0acc3fbc25:amazon-json-logger:jar:mule-plugin:1.0.6:compile
[INFO]    +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:anypoint-mq-rest-client:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    \- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.4.2:compile
```

Log4j 1.2.17 does not appear here.

I found this question asked before: [Why is Maven downloading log4j-1.2.12.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473780/why-is-maven-downloading-log4j-1-2-12-jar)
but the problem there was that `maven-compiler-plugin` was downloading log4j. I do not have this plug in.
The only plug ins I have are `mule-maven-plugin 3.3.5`, `maven-resources-plugin 3.0.2` and `munit-maven-plugin 2.2.5`

Why is this jar appearing in my filepath?

Comment: *I do not have this plug in.* is not true. You have, and your project using it even if you didn't configure that explicitly. Here is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75966547/5043481) what is Super POM and how `<pluginManagement>` works with plugins whose configured by default in Super POM.

Answer (score 0):

Your `log4j-1.2.17` is downloaded by a Maven plugin.

This is not harmful and you can safely ignore it. It will not be part of the application you build.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the name and version of the plugin, and a link for context?

Comment: It can be multiple plugins. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923954/944849) describing what the "effective POM" is, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691273/944849) which builds on that somewhat to explain how `pluginManagement` comes into play if used.